# AjaxControlToolit HTMLEditorExtender does not add bold, italic, subscript and superscript tags to the final submitted text

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit, htmleditorextender

I am using AjaxControlToolkit's HTMLEditorExtender in my website as:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Width="90%" Rows="20" 
 TextMode="MultiLine" Wrap="False" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="2px" 
 Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="Medium" ></asp:TextBox>

<asp:HtmlEditorExtender ID="TextBox2_HtmlEditorExtender" runat="server" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="TextBox2">
                   <Toolbar>
                   <asp:Undo />
                   <asp:Redo />
                   <asp:Bold />
                   <asp:Italic />
                   <asp:Underline />
                   <asp:StrikeThrough />
                   <asp:Subscript />
                   <asp:Superscript />
                   <asp:InsertOrderedList />
                   <asp:InsertUnorderedList />
                   <asp:RemoveFormat />
                   <asp:SelectAll />
                   <asp:UnSelect />
                   <asp:Delete />
                   <asp:Cut />
                   <asp:Copy />
                   <asp:Paste />
                   <asp:Indent />
                   <asp:Outdent />
                   <asp:FontNameSelector />
                   </Toolbar>
</asp:HtmlEditorExtender>
```

But the problem is whenever I write a text in text box and mark some of the characters as bold, italic, subscript or superscript, it removes them and stores in the database without these tags. So when I fetch the data to show on a page, all the tags work fine except these four. Please tell what should I do to solve this?

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you are getting the text from the extender, not the text box.  Use this text to save to the database:

```
Dim myHTMLText as string 
myHTMLText =TextBox2_HtmlEditorExtender.text
```

If you are already doing this, post your codebehind so we can take a look.

Comment: `HtmlEditorExtender` does not contain any `text` or `Text` property